# Getting 'divide by zero' error when numerator, not denominator is 0

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, amazon-redshift, divide-by-zero

I have a 'Divide by 0' mystery in Redshift that is NOT coming from the denominator being 0.

I have two columns that are both decimals:Sales is always > 0, and it's my denominator. "Flagged Sales" is between 0 and up to the value of Sales.

When I run the code below (using Postico to query Redshift) I get the correct results, except that when "Flagged Sales"=0 I would like the result to be 0, not NULL.

```
SELECT 
   NULLIF("Flagged Sales") / NULLIF(Sales,0)::decimal AS "% of Sales Flagged"
FROM Table1;
```

The following attempts to get 0 when the numerator is 0 have resulted in the 'Divide by zero' error:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (NULLIF("Flagged Sales",0) / NULLIF(Sales,0)::decimal) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE (NULLIF("Flagged Sales",0) / NULLIF(Sales,0)::decimal)
    END AS "% of Sales Flagged"
```

Same with:

```
COALESCE((NULLIF("Flagged Sales") / NULLIF(Sales,0)::decimal)) AS "% of Sales Flagged"
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you narrow down to a small set of data that can reproduce this problem and include it here?

Comment: When inexplicable errors like this pop up for me, I like to take as much out of the equation as possible.  I love Postico, but it is not made by the creators of Postgres, per se.  I might suggest that just for this query (while you debug it) that you see if you get the same results from the `psql` command line.  I have had a few cases where the GUI got in my way.  Perhaps this is one?

Comment: Shy of that, I might also suggest that you add a `WHERE` condition that lets you narrow down your dataset (binary search) to find the offending row(s).

Comment: can you try     where sales >0  and share the result.

Comment: @venial-steps please can you let me know whether my code below works for you?

Answer (score 0):

This following code works fine for all combinations of Flagged Sales and Sales

```
select COALESCE(("Flagged Sales" / NULLIF(Sales,0)),0) AS "% of Sales Flagged"
from (select 0 as "Flagged Sales", 0 as Sales) as a
;
```